# Changing UINavigationController from UItabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabBarController with 4 tabs. In the fist one I need to show an UINavigationController which has a UIView in it. When the user presses a button inside that view I need to display another UINavigationController in tab 1 replacing the old one. Is this possible? 
I tried using this code with no luck

```
UINavigationController *tableNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Nav2" bundle:nil];

[[self.tabBarController selectedViewController] setView:tableNavController.view];
```

This replaces the view but not the controller. 
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just push a fresh viewController onto tab 1's navigationController?

Comment: Hi Ben!, thanks for your answer, I'm quite new at iphone development can you explain me a bit how can I do that? My thing is that the NavigationController is created by using Interface Builder when selecting each tab's controller, so I dont know how to have access to it to change its View

Comment: You need a reference to it in one of your classes (probably whatever owns or creates the tab controller). Then you just use -pushViewController:animated:. I personally never use IB to create controllers; I always do that in code.